# Dubious about potting soil

Tags: potting-soil, onions

I'm planting onions in tubs right now and I'm rather iffy about the soil from one of the packs. It smelled odd compared to the other packs and was slightly paler, just enough to noice. Have I made a mistake using it? If so, what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about microbes or arthropods hitching a ride in your soil, you can always sterilize it in the oven. [This source](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/garden-how-to/soil-fertilizers/sterilizing-soil.htm) suggests 180-200*F for 30 min.